Is it possible to add a locale to Intl.DateTimeFormat?
I am building a multi-lingual website with the languages Dutch, English and Papiamentu (spoken on Curaçao and Bonaire). I can use Intl.DateTimeFormat with Dutch and English but Papiamentu seems to not be supported as I get everything back in English:
Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { dateStyle: 'full' }).format(new Date());
// "Wednesday, December 11, 2024" <= correct

Intl.DateTimeFormat('nl', { dateStyle: 'full' }).format(new Date());
// "woensdag 11 december 2024" <= correct

Intl.DateTimeFormat('pap', { dateStyle: 'full' }).format(new Date());
// "Wednesday, December 11, 2024" <= not correct as this is in English, expected "djaweps, 11 di desèmber 2024"

Is there a way to extend the dictionary used by Intl to add support for locales that it doesn't know? I'd like to do it without polyfills if possible.

Ik was benieuwd, maar lodybo.nl is niet online :/

Oh foutje, dat zal ik zo even fixen.. :)

@mplungjan hij is weer online!

Helaas niet....

It is alas not possible to extend the built-in INTL processing, but if the language syntax is not too complex, we can use some lookup tables.
Let me know if this works for you. Perhaps you want to add alternative (Aruba) spellings?
(Papiamento or Papiamentu?) https://nl.wiktionary.org/wiki/djaweps


const papiamentuMonths = [
    "di januari", "di febrüari", "di mart", "di aprel", "di mei", "di yüni", 
    "di yüli", "di ougustus", "di sèptèmber", "di òktober", "di nòvèmber", "di desèmber"
];

const papiamentuWeekdays = [
    "djadomingu", "djaluna", "djamars", "djawebs", "djaweps", "djabièrne", "djasabra"
];

const formatDateInPapiamentu = (date) => {
    const day = date.getDate();
    const month = papiamentuMonths[date.getMonth()];
    const year = date.getFullYear();
    const weekday = papiamentuWeekdays[date.getDay()];

    return `${weekday}, ${day} ${month} ${year}`;
}

console.log(formatDateInPapiamentu(new Date()));
// Output: "djaweps, 11 di desèmber 2024"




I think that's the way to go. I can write a sort of wrapper to handle papiamentu/papiamento (good catch on the difference) this way and "fall back" to Intl in other cases.
